# Apache not starting LAMP

Tags: apache, amazon-web-services, lamp

I have successfully started an AWS instance. I can connect with Putty and also
with WinSCP. I have ports 80 and 443 open and SSH port 22. I have installed LAMP successfully: Apache seems to start OK on the server:

```
[ec2-user ~]$ chkconfig --list httpd

httpd           0:off   1:off   2:on    3:on    4:on    5:on    6:off
```

but when I go enter the  public DNS address on the browser it gets timed out!

I also get this report from:

```
[ec2-user ~]$ ls -l /var/www

total 20
drwxrwsr-x 2 root www 4096 Mar 18 20:24 cgi-bin

drwxrwsr-x 3 root www 4096 Apr 16 21:41 error

drwxrwsr-x 2 root www 4096 Apr 16 22:32 html

drwxrwsr-x 3 root www 4096 Apr 16 21:41 icons

drwxrwsr-x 2 root www 4096 Apr 16 21:41 noindex

[ec2-user@ip-172-31-24-2 ~]$ ^C
[ec2-user@ip-172-31-24-2 ~]$
```

I'm totally new to this so any help much appreciated!

I'm using a Windows 7 machine and the AWS instance is linux.

Comment: Did you actually *run* apache ? check your logs.

Comment: Could you tell us a bit more about your server, specifically: the linux distribution (Centos, Ubuntu, etc.), and the AMI you used to create it?  Also, I assume by "have ports 80 and 443 open" you mean they're open in the AWS security group?

Comment: This can answer the AMI question (hopefully your instance has curl on it): `curl http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/ami-id`.

Answer (score 0):

Can you please send "sudo netstat -nltp". You also said 80 and 443 is open, are these opened via security groups, right?

Answer (score 0):

The first thing to check when a browser times out is the Security Group.  Do you have a rule in your instance's security group that will authorize traffic to TCP Port 80 and / or TCP port 443 ?

If this is correct and SSH connectivity to the instance is OK too (it rules out networking issues), then I would check if your Apache server is actually running.  Nothing from the command output shared in your question actually proof Apache is running.  Type `ps ax | grep http` to verify http daemon is running or not.  Also type `netstat -tnlp` as suggested in another reply to very `http` process is actually listening on port TCP 80 or TCP 443

Seb